# Switching to Terminal for Octave GUI output

Tags: macos, terminal, octave, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to figure out why, when I have a large output in the GNU Octave version 4.0.3 running on MacOSX ElCapitan GUI - `magic(500)` for example - and the "-- less -- (f)orward, (b)ack, (q)uit" prompt comes on screen I have to switch to the terminal to actually execute the command. It's kind of annoying to have to click the terminal just to type "q" so I can continue working in octave-gui after displaying a large output. It would be nice if I didn't have to take up space on my desktop with an open terminal window. I've had the GUI run the command from the command window, but I guess the settings got messed up in some way? Any help on this would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable paging within octave using a number of methods [listed here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Paging-Screen-Output.html).

```
more off
page_screen_output(false)
page_output_immediately(True)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps. Is there a way to keep the "more" option on without having to switch to the terminal to scroll through outputs?

Comment: @slap-a-da-bias How are you launching Octave?

Comment: Oh lol. I was launching it by clicking on the app icon. If I launch from the terminal it works the way I want it to... so that solves my problem. Thanks for your help!